# R Grep Function - working with the outcome matches to fill a column

Tags: r

I am trying to come with a solution for using grep function to a column of data and filling the grep matches with a number 1 and fill the mismatches with O´s but I just can´t come up with a solution (I am totally new to R, so what I am doing is probably going to make some folks lol).

```
info <- cbind(info, A_DO = ifelse(grep("DO",info[,"ACTUAL"])>0,1,0)
```

The info table looks like this:(I´ve included the last column as that is my desired ouput)

```
PLAZA_CR|TZ|LOCATION|FA|TIPO_REPARTO|ACTUAL|NUEVO|**A_DO**
10GTO|8|19973|3633|DIURNO|DO|MI|**1**
10GTO|8|19975|10198|DIURNO|LUJU|DO|**0**
10GTO|8|1237|3633|DIURNO|DO|LUJU|**1**
10GTO|8|20204|3633|DIURNO|DOMAJU|LUMIJU|**1**
10GTO|8|1108|3633|DIURNO|LUMIJU|DOMAJU|**0**
10GTO|8|10895|368|DIURNO|DO|DOMIVI|**1**
10GTO|8|9434|3634|DIURNO|DOMIVI|DO|**1**
10GTO|8|17403|3633|DIURNO|DOLUMAMIJUVI|MAVI|**1**
10GTO|8|17404|3633|DIURNO|MAVI|DOLUMAMIJUVI|**0**
10GTO|8|2585|368|DIURNO|LUJU|DOMIVI|**0**
10GTO|8|16927|3634|DIURNO|DOMIVI|LUJU|**1**
```

Comment: you could just do `info$A_DO <- grepl("DO",info$ACTUAL)*1`. `grepl` will output a boolean vector of `TRUE/FALSE`, multiplying by 1 converts it to 1s and 0s.

Comment: My R does not recognize that function grepl, it only recognizes: grep. I have R 2.8.1 is that the reason why It does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to as NiCE commented, you can use something like this, taking the output of grepl, which returns a logical vector for the matches:

```
info$A_DO <- as.numeric(grepl("DO", info[ , "ACTUAL"]))
```

So you don't need to use the cbind, as you can use the $ operator to create a new column of info, but you can use it if you'd prefer:

```
info <- cbind(info, A_DO = as.numeric(grepl("DO", info[ , "ACTUAL"])))
```

Comment: Thank you!  Does grepl come with the newest R Version or do I have to install another library, because my R does not seem to recognize the grepl function..??

Comment: Yes, grepl comes with the most recent R version. Trying ?grep to find it in base R.